# Number made from the first digits of $2^n$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, transcendental-numbers

Consider the number c made from the first digits of $2^n$. To be more precise, the
n-th decimal digit of c is the first digit of $2^n$. The first digits from c are :

0.24813612512481361251248136125124813612512481371251249137125124913712512491371361
24913713612491371361

At first sight, the number appears to be rational because apparent patterns appear 
showing periods. In fact, the continued fraction of c has very large convergents.
I calculated the first 20 000 digits from c with PARI and found a convergent with
amazing 5817 digits! The terms afterwards are totally normal. This leads to the 
conjecture that c is transcendental. Has anyone an idea how this can be proven ?

A similar situation is observed in champerov's constant 0.12345678910111213...
I read in the internet that this number also has extreme convergents without
having obvious periods. Does anyone know why the large convergents occur ?

Comment: Interesting question (+1). I'd guess it is almost surely transcendental although it does not seem we have enough tools currently to prove or disprove this.

Comment: FYI : http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C8%2C1%2C3%2C6%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C1%2C2%2C4&language=japanese&go=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2

Comment: I am surprised that this sequence is already in OEIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not a complete answer.

One thing that can be said is that this number is not a normal one, as $1$ appears more often that $2$, $2$ more often that $3$, etc.

Also, it is definitely not rational, as the probability of a digit to be equal to $1$ is $\log_{10} 2$, which is an irrational number.

Also, it can be expressed as
$$
\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left\lfloor 10^{n\log_{10}2-\lfloor n\log_{10}2\rfloor}\right\rfloor}{10^n}.
$$

Comment: An interesting application of benfords law.